# How to auto reply to email in GMAIL

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email, automation

I've managed to successfully auto reply to emails via the Gmail canned responses and using filters.

However, my use case is that I want to auto reply to some emails where the sender is **me** (the from email is my email and the reply to email is a different one).

For some reason, when the email sender is me, the email is detected by the filter and **mark as read** option is executed, however the **auto reply** don't.